# Matplotlib/Basemap figure size different when generated in script versus imported function

Tags: python, matplotlib, save, matplotlib-basemap

I have a script that makes a basic map and then exports the figure to a png file:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def basic_map():

    ##geographic boudning/projection info
    lon_0 = -119.610686
    lat_0 = 37.246066
    llcrnrlon = -129.409591
    llcrnrlat = 30.034156
    urcrnrlon = -109.131211
    urcrnrlat = 43.009518

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7205 / 600, 4308 / 600), dpi=600)
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.001, 0.001, .999, .999])

    m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=llcrnrlon, llcrnrlat=llcrnrlat, urcrnrlon=urcrnrlon, urcrnrlat=urcrnrlat, \
        resolution='l', lon_0=lon_0, lat_0=lat_0, projection='aea' \
        ,ellps='GRS80', lat_1=llcrnrlat, lat_2=urcrnrlat,ax=ax)
    m.drawcountries()
    m.drawstates()
    m.drawcoastlines()
    ax.axis('off')
    f = 'somewhere.png'
    plt.savefig(f, dpi=600, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)

basic_map()
```

When I run the script above it returns a png file with dimensions of 5358 × 4310 pixels (600 dpi). However, if import the nearly identical file (see below) as a module and then run the basic_map() function it returns a png file of size 1685 × 1356 pixels (600 dpi), i.e. ~3x smaller than original dimensions:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def basic_map():

    ##geographic boudning/projection info
    lon_0 = -119.610686
    lat_0 = 37.246066
    llcrnrlon = -129.409591
    llcrnrlat = 30.034156
    urcrnrlon = -109.131211
    urcrnrlat = 43.009518

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7205 / 600, 4308 / 600), dpi=600)
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.001, 0.001, .999, .999])

    m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=llcrnrlon, llcrnrlat=llcrnrlat, urcrnrlon=urcrnrlon, urcrnrlat=urcrnrlat, \
    resolution='l', lon_0=lon_0, lat_0=lat_0, projection='aea' \
    ,ellps='GRS80', lat_1=llcrnrlat, lat_2=urcrnrlat,ax=ax)
    m.drawcountries()
    m.drawstates()
    m.drawcoastlines()
    ax.axis('off')
    f = 'somewhere.png'
    plt.savefig(f, dpi=600, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

I then import this as a module and run the function:

```
import File as F 
F.basic_map()
```

Neither the script or the imported module/function report errors. The only difference that I have noticed is that when I run after importing the module/function there is a blank figure window that pops up.

I am running Python 3.5.4 (packaged by condo-forge) on a Mac running High Sierra (10.13).

Anyway, I am creating a larger mapping application and I need this to be a function that returns the larger sized file (from the script). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Both codes create an image of size 5224x4202 pixels when I run them. I would guess that there is something outside of the code that you show here causing the difference. Please make sure you provide [mcve]s (i.e. after posting the code, copy it from your question and run the copied version).

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. Unfortunately, these were copied directly from a file that I tested before my original post. I’m running this in PyCharm, could that be the problem?

Comment: They can't be directly copied, since that would produce some syntax errors. Also you would need two files. Put yourself in my position: I see the question, copy the code, run it. Make sure that if you do as I do, we get the same results. That is what is called reproducibility.

Comment: You're right. I tried it again and it worked. It took me a long time of playing with it to figure out what caused it to make the smaller figure. It is only when I import the file as a library and then call the function. In other words, if I call the second script Foo.py and then import Foo and call the basic_map function, it is the figure with the smaller dimensions.

Comment: This also should not happen, but importing it in another script somehow open even more doors for something being different. E.g. if you import some other module that would itself make some changes. Are you running this with python 3 in both cases? What happens if you add the axes to the basemap, `Basemap(..., ax=ax)`?

Comment: Yes, I a running Python 3.5.4 in both cases. If I add axes to Basemap nothing changes. However, there is another difference that I have noticed that is probably important. When I run it as a script no image window pops up; whereas when I run it as a function that I have imported there is a blank figure window that pops up.

Comment: Correct. That *is* important. It still sounds as though there is something else somewhere in the script happening. Do you mean `F.basic_map()` in the above code?

Comment: Yes -- thanks. I'll make that change! To your speculation, my original script was larger and more complex, but I stripped it down and I can recreate the problem with just the code that is posted above.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Or are you running this in terminal? The thing is, that noone else can probably reproduce this, so there must be something specific to your way of running things.

Comment: I am running this in PyCharm. I guess I feel somewhat vindicated knowing that my code is not the problem because I sure couldn't find a bug. If you can think of anything else I can try let me know. Otherwise, thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, yes try outside of PyCharm, as script in python or another IDE.

Comment: Running from the terminal worked! Thanks again.